# Why don't images show up in a post?

Tags: bug, specific-question, images

Why do the image links in the post [Triangle angle bisectors, trisectors, quadrisectors,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346142/triangle-angle-bisectors-trisectors-quadrisectors) show up as raw source?  (I tried deleting everything but the `[1]` or `[2]` in case the rest wasn't being processed somehow, but the preview suggested it didn't work.  I wonder if it has to do with the amount of raw HTML in the question itself, but I didn't want to fiddle with it and mess up anything else in the question.)

[image]

Comment: Posted problem to Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357552/222298

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a bug caused by the [recent migration to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232), and indeed it seems to be related to the large amount of HTML (I've encountered similar issues while [trying to fix broken images across the network](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f)).

I've fixed it by adding an extra newline between

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

and the images. They show up now.