# Why does Markdown not always work?

Tags: bug, markdown

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/368107/6094), I selected text
and marked it bold with two stars. But it displays for me (both in preview and after posting) like this:

[image]

Is this related to the move to CommonMark as noted in the post,
[Why don't images show up in a post?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4632/6094).
Is there something I need to update in my browser (MacOS/Chrome) to get Markdown working as it used to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a lot of HTML in that post; that shouldn't be a problem per se but I've seen cases where this interfered with the Markdown parser (even before the migration to CommonMark).

It's best to use only HTML or only Markdown within a single paragraph in your posts. Replacing `**Added 4Aug2020**` by `<b>Added 4Aug2020</b>` should do the trick, and adding a break between `<hr />` and `**Added 4Aug2020**.` works too.

Comment: "It's best to use only HTML or only Markdown within a single paragraph": Excellent advice--Thanks! And <b> worked.

Comment: Incidentally, this appears to be the same genre of problem that bit @JosephO'Rourke in the post I wrote about at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4632/why-dont-images-show-up-in-a-post , so it's good to have the general guidelines!